# Does the iOS status bar eat up background space in 7.0? Prior to 7.0?

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, ios-simulator, ios7

[idev101.com](http://www.idev101.com/code/User_Interface/launchImages.html) talked about loading images and clearly stated that the screens were exclusive of the status bar height.

In what I have seen under iOS 7, however, it appears that once one is *in* an app (not considering loading for the moment) the status bar is rendered over background, so that the background dimensions include some of what is under the status bar. (If you have mostly dark and black imagery at the top of your background and the status bar is black on background, it's a whole lot harder to read than black on a light background.)

So, and this may be opening a bit of a can of worms, if one is going to accommodate iOS 7 and previous iOS versions and the different iPhone and iPad resolutions, what are the bases necessary for complete coverage? I can see things being simpler if you say that a background doesn't have to exactly equal its space, but an image that can lose 20 pixels on the bottom is acceptable, but what are current rules and best practices for backgrounds that can be set for any resolution? E.g. on a new iPad 4 running iOS 7, should there be double 1024x768, with 20 pixels at the top light enough to contrast with black text (or, another question, is it possible to specify white or light status bar text and symbols that will contrast properly against a darker background)?

TIA,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On iOS6, the status bar is layed over the view controller only if `wantsFullScreen` is `YES` and the status bar and navigation controller styles are translucent.

On iOS7, by default, the view controllers are always full screen and the status bar and navigation bar are translucent. You could disable this, but it would really break the immersion of your app, especially if it displays content such as images.

On iOS7, why not set the status bar style according to your content? In iOS7, it is possible to decide status bar style per view controller:

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIViewController/preferredStatusBarStyle

You could calculate, and if your content is dark, return `UIStatusBarStyleLightContent`. This way, the status bar text will turn white. It is even possible to animate.

If you have one view controller which changes content, you can call `setNeedsStatusBarAppearanceUpdate` to update the status bar style.

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIViewController/setNeedsStatusBarAppearanceUpdate